# What's the difference between "That picture is scary" and "That picture was scary"?

Tags: tense

What's the difference between "That picture is scary" and "That picture was scary"?
I don't know the difference in meaning

Comment: The same as the difference between _is_ and _was_ normally is! 'It was scary' = I found it to be scary when I saw it at some time in the past.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is or was a great movie.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/156882/is-or-was-a-great-movie) Also [Book Is/Was Divided Into Sections](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/29462/book-is-was-divided-into-sections) and [Should I use "is" or "was"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4240/should-i-use-is-or-was), among others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**was** is the past tense of **is**, so if it *was* scary, it might be that you don't find it scary anymore, but you once found it scary. It *is* scary means that you still find it scary.

[image: https://www.gymglish.com/en/gymglish/english-grammar/conjugating-the-verb-to-be]

Image is "screenshotted" from [gymglish](https://www.gymglish.com/en/gymglish/english-grammar/conjugating-the-verb-to-be)

[Difference between is and was in English grammar](https://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-is-and-was-in-english-grammar/)

[What is the difference between is and was](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-is-and-was)